# OOP semantics of operations with arguments

Tags: oop

What are semantics of `OOP` in terms of operations that take arguments (other objects)?

A simple example would be an addition operation (or `equals` method for Java programmers out there).

I have an object that extends an integer and want to add another object that also extends an integer. One of them might be a complex number. The other could be tagged with display colour. Should addition retain both properties?

Are there any restrictions in `OOP` that limit scope of possible the results in general?

Comment: What do you mean by "Should addition retain both properties?" You can write an `add` method for both of it!

Answer (score 0):

There is no a priori restriction and the decision of the "generality" of the operation should be the higher that make sense in your project.

For instance

```
int + float -> float          : 1 + 3.14 -> 3.14
int + fraction -> fraction    : 1 + 1/3 -> 4/3
fraction + float -> float     : 1/3 + 3.14 -> 3.47333333333
int + polynomial -> polynomial: 1 + (x^2 + x + 2) -> x^2 + x + 3
```

and so on.

Of course, the receiver doesn't have to know how to operate with all kinds of arguments, and it will probably use double dispatching or some other technique to extend the operation as new argument types present.